# How to remove AJAX when updating the quantity of the product in the cart page - Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-theme-astra

I want to remove AJAX when changing quantity of products, instead of using AJAX I want to change quantity then execute by clicking update cart button.
Plugin: Woocommerce - version 7.7.0
Theme: Astra - version 4.1.3

Thanks for watching.